# inserting an empty line in between every two elements a column (data frame + pandas)

Tags: pandas, dataframe

My data frame looks something like this:

```
    Games
0   CAR 20
1   DEN 21
2    TB 31
3   ATL 24
4    SD 27
5    KC 33
6   CIN 23
7   NYJ 22

import pandas as pd
df =pd.read_csv('weekone.txt',)
df.columns=['Games']
```

I'm trying to put a blank line in between every two elements (teams).
So I want it to look like this:

```
    Games
0   CAR 20
1   DEN 21

2    TB 31
3   ATL 24

4    SD 27
5    KC 33

6   CIN 23
7   NYJ 22
```

But when I'm using this loop

```
    for i in df2.index:
        if (df2.index[i])%2 == 1:
            df2.Games[i]=df2.Games[i]+('\n')
        else:
             df2.Games[i] = df2.Games[i]
```

I'm getting an output like this:

```
      Games
0     CAR 20
1   DEN 21\n
2      TB 31
3   ATL 24\n
4      SD 27
5    KC 33\n
6     CIN 23
7   NYJ 22\n
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: are you asking about representation (i.e. how to print your DF in that way) or do you want to have empty lines (and empty indexes) in your DF (i.e. to have more rows)?

Comment: Hi, I want to have empty lines in my DF not just print it.

Thanks.

Comment: You also want to have empty entries for the index values?

Comment: Is it possible to show me  both ways ( empty lines in between index values and having index values represent the empty lines) I'm still undecided which way I want to have it and will have to play around with both. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it this way:

```
In [172]: x
Out[172]:
    Games
0  CAR 20
1  DEN 21
2   TB 31
3  ATL 24
4   SD 27
5   KC 33
6  CIN 23
7  NYJ 22

In [173]: %paste
empty_line = pd.DataFrame([''], columns=x.columns, index=[''])

rslt = x.loc[:1]
g = x.groupby(x.index//2)

for i in range(1, len(g)):
    rslt = pd.concat([rslt.append(empty_line), g.get_group(i)])
## -- End pasted text --

In [174]: rslt
Out[174]:
    Games
0  CAR 20
1  DEN 21

2   TB 31
3  ATL 24

4   SD 27
5   KC 33

6  CIN 23
7  NYJ 22
```

the index's dtype is `object` now:

```
In [178]: rslt.index.dtype
Out[178]: dtype('O')
```

or having `-1` as an index for empty lines:

```
In [175]: %paste
empty_line = pd.DataFrame([''], columns=x.columns, index=[-1])

rslt = x.loc[:1]
g = x.groupby(x.index//2)

for i in range(1, len(g)):
    rslt = pd.concat([rslt.append(empty_line), g.get_group(i)])
## -- End pasted text --

In [176]: rslt
Out[176]:
     Games
 0  CAR 20
 1  DEN 21
-1
 2   TB 31
 3  ATL 24
-1
 4   SD 27
 5   KC 33
-1
 6  CIN 23
 7  NYJ 22
```

index dtype:

```
In [181]: rslt.index.dtype
Out[181]: dtype('int64')
```

Comment: Thanks. This is really useful.

Comment: Hi. If I accept the answer will will the thread be locked? 
I"m still trying to understand the code you wrote, and I might have questions as I dig deeper so my concern is the thread will be locked and I won't be able to ask those questions.

Comment: @moondra, no, the question will not be locked, but it might attract less attention from different people, as they might think that there is nothing to answer any more...

Comment: I have a question. When rslt is first created it has the values of the first 
the first two rows from the dataframe x. And the groupby function you are using, is breaking up the dataframe in many different sections by rows of two.

So for the first iteration of your "for i in range" loop, shouldn't rslt and the first group (  first two rows) of groupby produce the same results, resulting in duplication of the first group?

The code is obviosly not doing that, so I must be misunderstanding the code. 

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @moondra, that's why i used `1` in the `range(1, len(g))`; the first group has index: `0`, so i skipped it

Comment: I see. Thank you so much for your explanation.